# Deleting an element from an hash table and printing the full table

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a key-value hash table and i've already got a couple of functions that i've found, one that inserts an element and another one that looks up an element with a given key, here's the code:

```
#define HASHSIZE 101
static key_value *hashtab[HASHSIZE]; /* pointer table */

unsigned hash(char *s);

typedef struct key_value
{                           /* table entry: */
    struct key_value *next; /* next entry in chain */
    char *key;             /* defined name */
    char *value;             /* replacement text */ 
} key_value;

/* hash: form hash value for string s */
unsigned hash(char *s)
{
    unsigned hashval;
    for (hashval = 0; *s != '\0'; s++)
        hashval = *s + 31 * hashval;
    return hashval % HASHSIZE;
}

/* lookup: look for s in hashtab */
key_value *lookup(char *s)
{
    key_value *np;
    for (np = hashtab[hash(s)]; np != NULL; np = np->next)
        if (strcmp(s, np->key) == 0)
            return np; /* found */
    return NULL;       /* not found */
}

/* install: put (key, value) in hashtab */
key_value *install(char *key, char *value)
{
    key_value *np;
    unsigned hashval;
    if ((np = lookup(key)) == NULL)
    { /* not found */
        np = (key_value *)malloc(sizeof(*np));
        if (np == NULL || (np->key = strdup(key)) == NULL)
            return NULL;
        hashval = hash(key);
        np->next = hashtab[hashval];
        hashtab[hashval] = np;
    }
    else                        /* already there */
        free((void *)np->value); /*free previous value */
    if ((np->value = strdup(value)) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    return np;
}
```

I now would like to make a couple of functions, one that will print an hash table in its entirety, and another one that will delete a member from that hash table with a given key. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Deleting and printing members is not more complicated than inserting or looking up members; what exactly is impeding your progress?

Comment: well i didn't make these functions myself i found them. I've tried to do this for the printing one:

void print_table(char *s){
    key_value *np;
    for (np = hashtab[hash(s)]; np != NULL; np = np->next)
        printf("Key:%s Value:%s\n", np->key, np->value);
}

but it just prints the element whose key is sent as an argument, i don't understand why because the lookup function goes trough all elements.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67830816/edit) the post to update it with the code you have tried. It is clearly only traversing a single bucket of the hash table. If you want to traverse the entire table then you should not call `hash` at all. You just start from index `0` of the table, iterate every element and print any element that is not NULL.

Comment: Always avoid [Cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). It never leads to a real solution. Take the time to understand what a hash-table is and how you create the buckets and then chain nodes in the event of a collision. That will allow you to write a function to delete a node from the list beginning in one of he buckets of your table. See [Coding up a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml) and [Hash tables - eternally confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx)

Comment: The function you posted in the comment has already one fundamenta flaw: If you want to print a hash table in its entirety you shouldn't have a string argument to the function. After all, what should this string represent? Kaylum has told you how to print all buckets.